# Sybase Select select statement getting Hang

Tags: sybase, sap-ase, sap-iq

In our system, we are dropping some DML statements in Flat File and with the help of executing SQL task i am hitting it to Sybase DB, sometime select statement get hang. Don't know how can i resolve, i am updating the statistics also but still facing problem, there are 1000(Approx) of DML hit every 2-5 mins to sybase.

Please let me know the resolution

Comment: Sybase ASE or Sybase IQ? (2 different products with completely different query engines); if ASE, review the query plan for the SELECT; you can also, while the SELECT is running, run sp_who and query the MDA tables to see if the query is really hung (eg, being blocked) or busy running a poor query plan (eg, repeated queries of monProcessObject/monProcessActivity will show ever increasing IOs and cpu)

Comment: It is Sybase ASE. I try to update statistics and index rebuild, but it doesn't have any impact.